# Redirect all routes to one url until condition is met

Tags: php, symfony

I have a user entity, which has a boolean "hasTmpPassword". This boolean is set to true until the user changes its password.

After login with the temp password, I redirect to my changePassword page (with DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler )

How can I prevent a login user (with temp password), to access other pages of the website, and always redirect him toward the changePassword page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. after login that user you should set flag in his session (ie.
   changePasswordNeeded).

   $request->getSession()->set('changePasswordNeeded', true);
2. Add listener, which will be fired onKernelRequest

   kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
       class: YourLitenerClass
       tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelRequest }
3. Redirect to form each request except change_temp_password request
   (for selected users)

   public function onKernelRequest(FilterControllerEvent $event) {

   ```
     $request = $event->getRequest();

     if ($request->getSession()->has('changePasswordNeeded')) {
       $expectedRoute = 'change_temp_password';
       if ($expectedRoute === $event->getRequest()->get('_route')) {
         return;
       }

       $url = $this->router->generate($expectedRoute);
       $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
       $event->setResponse($response); 
     }        
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with symfony2, but in plain php I would set a session variable to indicate that a temporary password was used for authentication. Then you can check if that variable is set / has a certain value where you handle your authentication and redirect to the password-change page whenever the user tries to access another page.